# Spark streaming, kafka broker error, "Failed to get records for spark-executor- .... after polling for 512"

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

We have a spark streaming application reading data from Kafka.
Data size: 15 Million

Below errors were seen:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Failed to get records for spark-executor- after ...polling for 512 at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
```

There were more errors seen pertaining to CachedKafkaConsumer

```
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:227)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:193)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:214)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:866)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:926) 
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:670) 
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283) 
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.poll.ms is set to default 512ms and other Kafka stream timeout settings are default.

```
"request.timeout.ms" 
"heartbeat.interval.ms" 
"session.timeout.ms" 
"max.poll.interval.ms"
```

Also, the Kafka is being recently updated to 0.10 from 0.8. In 0.8, this behavior was not seen.
No resource issues are seen.

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you now starting the job reading all 15 million messages from beginning? With kafka version 0.8, did you also read all 15 million messages at once or was the data flowing continously over a longer period?

Comment: 15M is the total ingested data. The data was flowing continuously over a longer period. The processing went smooth till 2.5M data ingest, however, errors were seen around ~ 3.5M ingest.